# SQL Server 2008 R2: geometry data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, geometry, union

My question is simple, I want to use union for two queries which has a geometry data type in it and it gives me this error.

This is my query:

```
select 
    f.*, f.geom.STArea() as area, f.geom.STLength() as perimeter  
from 
    [dbo].[nosazi_shahrsazi_conne_leftJ]() as f,
    (select geom 
     from dbo.[GetWithinParcelWithApoint]('POLYGON ((5727454.0875024563 3838386.9047163716, 5727454.0875024563 3838391.8829422966, 5727459.06572838 3838391.8829422966, 5727459.06572838 3838386.9047163716, 5727454.0875024563 3838386.9047163716))') g) as h
where 
     h.geom.STTouches ( f.geom ) = 1 

union 

(select * 
 from dbo.[GetWithinParcelWithApoint]('POLYGON ((5727454.0875024563 3838386.9047163716, 5727454.0875024563 3838391.8829422966, 5727459.06572838 3838391.8829422966, 5727459.06572838 3838386.9047163716, 5727454.0875024563 3838386.9047163716))') g)
```

In fact I want to find all touching shapes around a shape and add the shape itself into result ..so I must use a union ..

Is there any way to fix this error? Thanks

Comment: well ,this may help others. Just change Union to Union All and everything work fine

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2009** version - we have 2000, 2005, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012, 2014 and 2016 - take your pick!

Comment: @marc_s oh,it was my mistake..I am on 2009 r2.Questin is edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if the error is inside of `dbo.[GetWithinParcelWithApoint]`. If so, we need to see the text.

From visible errors, you MUST use `UNION ALL` for `GEOMETRY` data type.